# Print responsive website in a desktop layout

Tags: css, html, printing, responsive-design

I am currently doing a responsive website. However, when I print the website the layout is in mobile layout. (like some text content will be replaced by dropdown menu as I designed.) One requirement now is making the page print in desktop layout by users.

For example, when I print getbootstrap.com in chrome it will print the mobile layout without the menu. How can I print one that zoom the desktop page and print in desktop layout?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have `@media print` query applied in the correct place in your CSS file. For example:

```
@media print and (min-width: 1024px) {
}
```